# fullcalendar border issue in agenda view

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, zurb-foundation

I experienced some issues with fullcalendar with agenda view.
In the week view, I have no vertical border inside the grid, as you can see in this picture :
http://cjoint.com/14av/DDlkmc7Kjgp.htm
In basic view, I have vertical borders.

I already tried what I found in this post [FullCalendar dividing lines between days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465392/fullcalendar-dividing-lines-between-days) without any success.

I'm using fullcalendar along with zurb foundation.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewRender: function(view,element){

       $('#calendar table').css('background-color','transparent');

       $('#calendar tr.fc-minor').attr('style','background:initial;');

       $('#calendar table').css('margin-bottom','0');

}
```

Notice that I only use agendaWeek view of fullcalendar, so I am not sure whether it also works to solve css compatibility problem on other views.

Add the code to your script when initial fullcalendar, in case you don't want to change the source code of foundation5 css

The first 2 line is to fix the problem of disappear border line and today highlight, and the third line is to fix the header row layout problem