# How can I show separation between days in a FullCalendar ResourceTimeline?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using the Resource Timeline view more or less as shown here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-custom-view-demo, but I'd like to show a separation between days because otherwise it's really difficult to tell where one day ends and another begins.

Something like this (though behind the events obviously):
[image]

The question was already asked ages ago here: [FullCalendar dividing lines between days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465392/fullcalendar-dividing-lines-between-days), but the answers don't work with Fullcalendar 4.

Comment: The answers in that question refer to a different view type anyway, so even if the version of fullCalendar was the same, it likely still wouldn't work. have you tried inspecting the rendered HTML of fullCalendar to see if it's possible to identify a pattern of elements which occur and mark the boundary between days. e.g. there are slat cells for the columns such as `<td class="fc-widget-content fc-major" data-date="2020-03-14T00:00:00"
"><div></div></td>` on which you could set a border colour (if you find all the midnight ones by their data-date attribute)

Comment: @ADyson I looked for any obvious classes, but wasn't able to identify any. What would be the CSS rule to target a regex on a data value such as you suggest? Could you give an example? Thanks

Comment: Actually, this works: `td[data-date$="00:00:00"] { border-left: 3px solid; }`

Comment: you should add it as an Answer then, below. You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial solution: As @ADyson suggested, it's possible to target the table cells using the `data-date` attribute. Unfortunately this is a bit fragile. At the moment, our calendar shows visible hours from 8am to 6pm, so I have to target `td` cells which have a data attribute of `"08:00:00"` as follows:

```
  td[data-date$="08:00:00"] {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
  }
```

And this highlights the cells as below (though you can see that the red line is in fact below the horizontal grid lines

[image: targeting the TD cells]

However, this doesn't affect the header cells. I can add another rule:

```
  th[data-date$="08:00:00"] {
    border-left: 1px solid yellow;
  }
```

But when the border width is only 1px, it doesn't show up, even if I add `important`. If I make it 2px wide, then it works. So here are the final CSS rules:

```
  th[data-date$="08:00:00"] {
    border-left: 2px solid red;
  }

  td[data-date$="08:00:00"] {
    border-left: 2px solid red;
  }
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image: targeting TD and TH with 2px thickness]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this going using a similar method to above on version 3 of FullCalendar, by using the eventAfterAllRender method as my start and end hours can differ

```
    $(".fc-timeline .fc-head .fc-time-area tr:first-child th").attr("style", "border-left-color: #C0C1C1 !important; border-right-color: #C0C1C1 !important")

    $(".fc-timeline .fc-head .fc-time-area tr:nth-child(2) th[data-date$='" + startString + "']").attr("style", "border-left-color: #C0C1C1 !important")
    $(".fc-timeline .fc-head .fc-time-area tr:nth-child(2) th[data-date$='" + finishString + "']").attr("style", "border-right-color: #C0C1C1 !important")

    $(".fc-timeline .fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-bg .fc-slats td[data-date$='" + startString + "']").attr("style", "border-left-color: #C0C1C1 !important")
```

Where the start/finishStrings look like "08:00:00" for example

[image]